# DropDownList or DropDownListFor in MVC3 Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a report that shows a list with the following columns:

```
A key column
A dropdown list showing a list of possible status
A title
```

This is the razor code:

```
@foreach (AdminSummary adminSummary in @Model.AdminSummaries) {
                index++;
                <div class="rep_tr0">
                    <div class="rep_td0" id="rk_@(index)">@adminSummary.RowKey</div>
                    <div class="rep_td0"><a href="/Administration/Products/Edit?&ac=@Model.Meta.AccountID&pr=@Model.Meta.ProductID&pa=@adminSummary.RowKey">Edit</a></div>            
                    <div class="rep_td0"><a href="/Administration/Products/Delete?&ac=@Model.Meta.AccountID&pr=@Model.Meta.ProductID&pa=@adminSummary.RowKey">Delete</a></div>  
                    <div class="rep_td0">@Html.DropDownListFor(??, ??)</div>
                    </div>
            }
```

I also have the following class:

```
public static class AdminStatusReference
    {

        public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetAdminStatusOptions()
        {
            return new[]
                {
                    new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Released"  },
                    new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "Review" },
                    new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "New" }
                };
        }

}
```

What I am not sure is how I can link these up. I know in the model I can store the list of
status options something like this:

```
vm.StatusList  = GetAdminStatusOptions();
```

But how can I create the dropdownlist. I am very confused with all of the options of DropDownList and
DropDownListFor.  Which should I be using and how can I send in the list of statuses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I am not sure is how I can link these up.

This will depend on how the model looks like.

But here's what you could do:

```
@for (var index = 0; index < Model.AdminSummaries.Count; index++)
{
    <div class="rep_tr0">
        <div class="rep_td0" id="rk_@(index)">
            @Model.AdminSummaries[index].RowKey
        </div>
        <div class="rep_td0">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(
                x => x.AdminSummaries[index].Status,
                AdminStatusReference.GetAdminStatusOptions()
            )
        </div>
        <div class="rep_td0">
            @Model.AdminSummaries[index].Title
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Thanks Darin, I was just busy correcting my question and you already gave me an answer. I'll check this out now.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to get back to you. AdminSummaries is as follows:  public IEnumerable<AdminSummary> AdminSummaries { get; set; }  When I try to run the code I get a runtime error message: Compiler Error Message: CS0021: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Selftestware.Storage.Models.AdminSummary>'

Comment: @Samantha2, OK, change it to be an `IList<AdminSummary>` or `AdminSummary[]` so that you can access elements by index.

Comment: Also need to change the "i" to "index" on the first line just in case someone tries to use this solution :-)  Thanks for your VERY fast response. Where should I make the change you are suggesting?

Comment: @Samantha2, inside the class where the `AdminSummaries` property is defined.

Comment: I made the change you are suggesting but many other things now start to give an error for example: summaries = summaries.OrderBy(item => item.Position).ThenBy(item => item.Title);  lots of syntax errors when it is set to IList<adminSummary>  I do some LINQ queries and send the results to the AdminSummaries class.

Comment: @Samantha2, add a `.ToList()` at the end of those queries. For example  `summaries = summaries.OrderBy(item => item.Position).ThenBy(item => item.Title).ToList();`.